# Linearly independent subset of the domain in a linear transformation implies linear independence of subset of codomain

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T : R^n \rightarrow  R^m$ be a linear transformation and $S = \{\vec{v_1}, \vec{v_2}, · · · , \vec{v_k}\}$ be a subset of $R^n$. Prove that if the set $\{T(\vec{v_1}), T(\vec{v_2}), · · · , T(\vec{v_k})\}$ is a linearly independent subset of $R^m$, then $S$ is a
linearly independent subset of $R^n$

My attempt:

Suppose set $\{T(\vec{v_1}),T(\vec{v_2}),...,T(\vec{v_k})\}$ is linearly independent.

$T(\vec{v_1}) = A\vec{v_1}$, where $A$ is the standard matrix of the transformation. Realize that the set is a set of columns of $AV$ where $A\in\mathcal{M}_{mxn}, V\in\mathcal{M}_{nxk}$. Thus the set of columns of $AV$ is linearly independent. To prove that $S$ is linearly independent, $V$ has to be invertible. But I can't prove that, since I don't have any information regarding matrix $A$. Or is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\alpha_1v_1+...+\alpha _k v_k=0&\implies T(\alpha _1v_1+...+\alpha _kv_k)=0\\
&\implies \alpha _1T(v_1)+...+\alpha _kT(v_k)=0\\
&\implies \alpha _1=...=\alpha _k=0.
\end{align*}

I let you justify each step properly.

Comment: I am sorry. Can you please explain more? I don't understand how your answer can help me...

Comment: @SharonZh: It would be easier if you can explain what is unclear. Because it's difficult to give much more details...

Comment: I don't know which one is the vector and which one is a constant...

Comment: @SharonZh: Come on ! Of course $v_i$ are vectors (it's how you denote them), and $\alpha _i$ are not constant, but  scalar. And of course, I check that the definition of linear independence hold...

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. After staring at it for 10 minutes I finally get it. But, I don't think $v_i$ is how you denote vectors? (at least according to my lessons) I am pretty sure you have to either bold it or put a bar/arrow on top.

Comment: there is no obligation to put bar, or arrow on vector. Vectors are nothing else than element of a vector space. But if it helps you to add bar or arrow, you can of course add them :)